# How do I configure the relationships in these Grails classes to cascade properly?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Here's a simplified version of the classes I'm using:

```
class Foo {
    Bar importantBar

    static hasMany = [ bars: Bar ]
}

class Bar {
    static belongsTo = [ foo: Foo ]
}
```

Now, the `Bar` that's in the `Foo` class as `importantBar` can also exist in the `bars` set.  What I want to have happen is when I delete a `Bar`, and it happens to be an `importantBar`, I want it to be deleted from both places in the `Foo` object.  Declaring `static hasOne = [ importantBar: Bar ]` has not worked either, as when I add a new `Bar` to the `bars` set, it is automatically being set as the `importantBar` property of the `Foo` class.  I don't want that to happen.

Is there any sort of mapping I don't know about that can do what I'm asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is [static mappedBy](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/mappedBy.html)

Comment: Nice, thanks.  Completely missed that one in the documentation.